# How to calculate previous and next quarter from a given quarter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to calculate the previous and next quarter when I pass the current quarter value. So for e.g. if I pass 'Q3' or 'Q4',

Output should be:

```
Current Quarter           Previous Quarter             Next Quarter
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     Q3                         Q2                         Q4
     Q4                         Q3                         Q1
```

Is there a function available in Oracle to achieve the same?

How can I arrive to this output using Select Query?

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6be7f/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE quarters ( value ) AS
  SELECT 'Q' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;
```

**Query 1** Using `SUBSTR` and `MOD` to calculate the next/previous values:

```
SELECT value As current_q,
       'Q' || ( MOD( SUBSTR( value, 2 ), 4 ) + 1 ) AS next_q,
       'Q' || ( MOD( SUBSTR( value, 2 ) + 2, 4 ) + 1 ) AS prev_q
FROM   quarters
```

**Query 2** Using `CASE` to enumerate the possibilities:

```
SELECT value AS current_q,
       CASE value
       WHEN 'Q1' THEN 'Q2'
       WHEN 'Q2' THEN 'Q3'
       WHEN 'Q3' THEN 'Q4'
       WHEN 'Q4' THEN 'Q1'
       END As next_q,
       CASE value
       WHEN 'Q1' THEN 'Q4'
       WHEN 'Q2' THEN 'Q1'
       WHEN 'Q3' THEN 'Q2'
       WHEN 'Q4' THEN 'Q3'
       END As prev_q
FROM   quarters
```

**Query 3** using `DECODE` to enumerate the possibilities:

```
SELECT value AS current_q,
       DECODE( value, 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1' ) AS next_q,
       DECODE( value, 'Q1', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q1', 'Q3', 'Q2', 'Q4', 'Q3' ) AS prev_q
FROM   quarters
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6be7f/7/2)** (for all the queries):

```
| CURRENT_Q | NEXT_Q | PREV_Q |
|-----------|--------|--------|
|        Q1 |     Q2 |     Q4 |
|        Q2 |     Q3 |     Q1 |
|        Q3 |     Q4 |     Q2 |
|        Q4 |     Q1 |     Q3 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't let you convert from a quarter back to a full date.

The simplest thing is probably to hard-code the combinations, as there are so few:

```
with t (current_quarter) as (
            select 'Q1' from dual
  union all select 'Q2' from dual
  union all select 'Q3' from dual
  union all select 'Q4' from dual
)
select current_quarter,
  case current_quarter
    when 'Q1' then 'Q4'
    when 'Q2' then 'Q1'
    when 'Q3' then 'Q2'
    when 'Q4' then 'Q3'
    else 'invalid'
  end as previous_quarter,
  case current_quarter
    when 'Q1' then 'Q2'
    when 'Q2' then 'Q3'
    when 'Q3' then 'Q4'
    when 'Q4' then 'Q1'
    else 'invalid'
  end as next_quarter
from t;

CU PREVIOU NEXT_QU
-- ------- -------
Q1 Q4      Q2     
Q2 Q1      Q3     
Q3 Q2      Q4     
Q4 Q3      Q1
```

You could do it mathematically though, by splitting out the numeric part and adjusting it:

```
with t (current_quarter) as (
            select 'Q1' from dual
  union all select 'Q2' from dual
  union all select 'Q3' from dual
  union all select 'Q4' from dual
)
select current_quarter,
  'Q' || (mod(to_number(substr(current_quarter, 2, 1)) + 2, 4) + 1) as previous_quarter,
  'Q' || (mod(to_number(substr(current_quarter, 2, 1)), 4) + 1) as next_quarter
from t;

CU PREVIOUS_QUARTER                          NEXT_QUARTER                             
-- ----------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------
Q1 Q4                                        Q2                                       
Q2 Q1                                        Q3                                       
Q3 Q2                                        Q4                                       
Q4 Q3                                        Q1
```

You *could* (ab)use date manipulation by breaking out the numeric quarter number and offsetting from a nominal date:

```
with t (current_quarter) as (
  select 'Q1' from dual
  union all select 'Q2' from dual
  union all select 'Q3' from dual
  union all select 'Q4' from dual
)
select current_quarter,
  to_char(add_months(date '2000-01-01',
    3 * (to_number(substr(current_quarter, 2, 1)) - 2)), '"Q"Q') as previous_quarter,
  to_char(add_months(date '2000-01-01',
    3 * to_number(substr(current_quarter, 2, 1))), '"Q"Q') as next_quarter
from t;

CU PR NE
-- -- --
Q1 Q4 Q2
Q2 Q1 Q3
Q3 Q2 Q4
Q4 Q3 Q1
```

but that seems to be getting needlessly complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with tst as
(
  Select level as lvl from dual CONNECT BY Level < 5
)
Select 'Q'||lvl as current_quarter,
'Q'||case when lvl = 1 then 4 else lvl -  1 end as previous_quarter,
'Q'||case when lvl = 4 then 1 else lvl +  1 end as next_quarter
from tst
```